# ORDER BY not sorting the records

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

I am trying to do Order by to fetch the records from higher to lower values , but the sorting is not happening, i am getting the records randomly.

Here is my code , please let me know , where i am going wrong:

```
public void fetchTopRecords() {

    int i = 0;

     String where = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_2 + " ORDER BY "
     + COL_C + " ASC LIMIT 6";
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery(where, null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String pckname = c.getString(COL_A);
                array_pck.add(pckname);
                int marks = c.getInt(COL_C);
                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: To get your valuesrecords from higher to lower values your should use DESC not ASC.

Comment: How have you defined the `COL_C` at create table statement? As `TEXT` or `INTEGER`?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code it will work :

```
public void fetchTopRecords() {
   String where = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_2 + " ORDER BY "
    + COL_C + " DESC LIMIT 6";
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(where, null);
   if (c != null) {
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
             String pckname = c.getString(COL_A);
             array_pck.add(pckname);
             int marks = c.getInt(COL_C);                
          } while (c.moveToNext());
       }
   }
```